# Nativebase : change thumbnail default size

Tags: size, thumbnails, native-base, react-props

I can't change the default size of the thumbnail from NativeBase. I can display the default circle, which is the small and the large one, but I want to display a bigger circle than the default size. Here's my code for the thumbnail :

```
<Thumbnail size={200} style={{margin: 30}} source={require('../../../public/images/profile/yellow.jpg')} />
```

The props size doesn't work, the thumbnail remains small.

My NativeBase version : 2.3.5

Answer (score 6):

Native Base Component doesn't have a `size` props, you should add `width` and `height`, and one more thing you shouldn't forget please add `borderRadius` divided by 2 to ensure the shape is retain Circle

```
<Thumbnail style={{width: 30, height: 30, borderRadius: 30/2}} source={require('../../../public/images/profile/yellow.jpg')} />
```

Comment: thats the right answer i've been looking for a long time , thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply increase the Thumbnail size by using this trick. Just take the property of `scale` with `<Thumbnail/>`.

Just copy-paste the below code in your app

```
<Thumbnail 
scaleX={3} scaleY={3} style={{margin: 30}} 
source={require('../../../public/images/profile/yellow.jpg')}/>
```

You can change the scale values as per your need. Let me know if this fixes your issue.

Answer (score 1):

The [Thumbnail](https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#Thumbnail) component from NativeBase doesn't have the `size` attribute. Try to set `width` and `height` properties of the `style` attribute

```
<Thumbnail style={{width: 100, height: 100, margin: 30}} source={require('../../../public/images/profile/yellow.jpg')} />
```

Answer (score 1):

NativeBase Thumbnail component comes with `small` and `large` props for size. You can also set width and height to have image with other dimensions

[image]